# lazy var or let for UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

When i want to add a `UIButton` in a view controller's view, here are the ways:

**First**

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton()
```

then configure properties in `viewDidLoad` method.

**Second**

```
lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let buttonTemp = UIButton()
    buttonTemp.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: "connect", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonTemp)
    return buttonTemp
}()
```

**Third**

```
let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return button
    }()
```

My question is which way should i use or which way is better?

1. I dislike the first way because i have to add an extra method to configure other properties.
2. Second is ok for me, i just need call `button` anywhere i want to.
3. I think use let is suit the best so i use the third way, but the thing is i can't call `self`, which is if i add this link in the closure:

   button.addTarget(self, action: "connect", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

I got the error:

`ViewController.swift:24:26: Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`

So i have add this line(any line with `self`) out of this closure. Any way can solve this?

Summary, which way is better or suit? Or any better way? thanks!

**EDIT**:

When i am using Objective C, i'd like use getter in this way

```
- (UIButton *) button {
    if (!_button) {
        _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        ...
    }
    return _button;
}
```

so my `viewDidLoad` will be clean and looks good:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   ...
   [self.view addSubview:self.button];
   ...
}
```

Comment: Storyboards and nibs in general are a massive pain to maintain in a huge team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styles obviously vary, but where I work we've standardized on the following approach:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)

            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouched:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            button.otherProperty = ...

            return button
        }()

        view.addSubview(button)

        // add constraints for button
    }

    func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton) {
        print("boop")
    }
}
```

The problem with all of your approaches is that:

- They're very verbose and not contained in a function, and
- You don't have access to `self` as you've seen

With the approach above (using a force-unwrapped optional), you get the benefit of deferred initialization (i.e. everything happens in `viewDidLoad()`), you know because you own the object that `button` will never be `nil` (thus you don't have to use conditional binding all over the place), and you get contained initialization for all of your `UIView` properties in one place.

You can obviously (and we do) make your `viewDidLoad()` function look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createViews()
    addSubviews()
    addViewConstraints()
}
```

Then you get even better specialization in your functions and your code stays organized.

Comment: If there are many controls, ```viewDidLoad``` will be very long.

Comment: That's why I gave the example at the end of using specialized functions.  Put view initialization in `createViews()`, etc.